# Best way to bind json files in one sqlite file

Tags: json, sqlite

For about 80 MB of JSON data it takes about 2-3 hours to insert it into one database file, plus a lot of other resources. What is the best way to write multiple JSON files in one SQLite database file? Can I write a SQLite header into a file convert the strings in readable data by the SQLite and close it. There can be data corruption errors, how to solve them and how to avoid them? Except the standard insert row method or multiple rows insert there is another quick fix for this problem?

By the SQLite website: https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html  there is some information about the file, can this be a good starting point?

Edited:

```
  foreach ($aTempHandler as $i => $sBufferTemp)
  {

    #var_dump("\n______________ sBufferTemp");
    if (empty($sBufferTemp)) continue;
    $oTemp = json_decode($sBufferTemp);
    
    #var_dump("\n______________ oTemp");
    if (!is_object($oTemp)) continue;
    if(empty($oTemp->date)) continue;

    if (empty($this->check_table_exists($oTemp->date)))
    {
      if (empty($this->reate_table($oTemp->date)))
      {
        $this->configure();
      }
      print_r("Create table for: ". $oTemp->date ."\n");
    }

    if ($z == 2000) {
      print_r($oTemp->id ." -> ". count($aTempHandler) ."\n");
      $z = 0;
    }

    unset($oTemp->{'id'});
    $bInsert = $this->insert_row($oTemp->date, $oTemp);

    #continue;
    $z++;
    $x = 1;
    
  }



public function insert_row($sp_, $oTemp)
{
    $aTemp = (array) $oTemp;
    $aForInsert = array(
      'time' => $aTemp['time'],
      'note' => (isset($aTemp['note']) ? json_encode($aTemp['note']) : null), 
    );

    print_r('.');
    return $this->db->exec("INSERT INTO $sp_ (". implode(",", array_keys($aForInsert)) .") VALUES ('". implode("','", array_values($aForInsert)) ."');");
  }
```

The above code is the part where it iterates over the lines from the JSON file. I replaced some of the data for other reasons. After creating the tables is the insert_row function where the query is built and executed. This part takes the longest time because every time separately I need to build the query and execute it for data to be placed in the corresponding table. Even if another loop is made to build a larger query will have the same consequences or will be even harder for my Dual-Core i5 processor/16 Gb Ram/MacSSD.

References

Database file format. (n.d.). SQLite. https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html

JSON. (n.d.). JSON. https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: 80 megabytes (MB). I have edited now, thanks.

Comment: Please show a sample of your JSON data and the technique you currently use that is too slow, i.e. an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MarkSetchell is a .json file with many PHP arrays encoded to JSON strings. A script reads an index and if the .json file exists it opens and row by row in a foreach inserts data in a sql database. After it finish it moves the file so the script that reads the index does not find it and skip to next one.

Comment: Please show some representative code for your inner loop. There is plenty that you could be doing wrong or *"sub-optimally"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell here you go, I have edited the post and added some part of the code.

Comment: What's in `insert_row()` please?

Comment: It builds the query and executes it

Comment: Have you considered starting a transaction, doing a few thousand `INSERT`s and then committing? Have you considered placing your database on a RAMdisk while you are populating it and then moving it to a hard-disk when you are finished?